# How to zoom chart line same as legend hover and reset automatically on button click in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

[image]

I have mention problem in image for highchart.
On mouse hover of Legend particular chart line's width is increased. Same thing i want to perform on label hover or click.
Can anyone help please.

Answer (score 1):

You can catch [legendItemClick](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#plotOptions.line.events.legendItemClick) event and modify `lineWidth` by update function.

http://jsfiddle.net/9PGvf/2/

Zoom can be achieved by [setExtremes](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Axis.setExtremes%28%29)

Comment: If you see in highcharts, if we do mouse hover on legend, line width will automatically increased and on mouse out it is automatically set as default. Same thing i have to perform on label.

I try with update function. In that it comes on top after updation. So, I can't see other lines.

Comment: But you want it on hover on label or click? I feel a little bit confused

Comment: I want that mouse hover functionality on mouse click on my custom label.